# Using localstorage

Tags: html, local-storage

Got myself in a tricky situation. I'm using local storage to save values from a popup window, and then paste them into an input when focus returns to parent window.

But then something rather awkward takes place, when I try to store ';' separated values, is that I get only the 1st set, losing all the rest of the string. What makes it more bizarre is that after saving my value, I test by calling

```
alert('SELECTED : ' +   localStorage.getItem('MyStr'));
```

the whole string is there... but on the script I retrieve this value, when i'm checking

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('MyStr'));
```

Only the 3rd set is there, i.e.: I store something like

> abcdefg;123323;ffasfs;5445;iuiuifa;

but when I need to get it back, theres only

> ffasfs

I could use some help then, I'm all new to this whole thing, and killing myself to get a website working.
Thanks in advance, sorry if my question looks stupid.

Comment: Could this be a race condition between the multiple windows accessing localStorage?

Comment: I don't know what it is. but actually it works fine for another page, only for the ';' separated values that it fails. I implemented this thing before, and it's allright. only problem seems to be the ';' or i don't know..
What i do is that, i call a script function after click event on popup window, close it, and then the focus returns to the parent window.
There i retrieve localstorage value. very simple... but yet tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your values in localStorage as JSON strings. This may even help you build more complex objects for the future.

For now though... Just do:

localStorage.setItem("your key", JSON.stringify("abcdef;1234;whatever"));

This procedure will not only sanitize your input but also create oppertunity to store serialized objects in the future.

It's important to note that while JSON.stringify is pretty much supported everywhere... Not all browsers have it built in.

For those cases, check out json2.js.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I *strongly suspect* that the browsers which don't have JSON.stringify would not have localstorage support either...

Comment: compare [CanIUse JSON Parsing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json) and [CanIUse Web Storage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)

Comment: Thanks Erik5388. I tried that, but still the same. That's a mistery. I don't know how such incredible things happen to me.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet for us to inspect on js fiddle?

Comment: I tried <<localstorage.VarName=MyString>>, which probably created that var on the fly, and was able to store the ';' separated string and retrieve it correctly on the parent page. Weird, but it worked,that's what matters now!
My question is, how do i delete this var now? And if you have the time, WTH was going on?
Thanks a lot, everybody!